# Hunting down a mysterious character displaying in view

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

I have a gigantic view, approx 1500 lines, that has multiple tables on it which are populated via SQL. I'm having an issue where there's a random p character showing up on my view. I've viewed source, inspected the element, and it reveals a p surrounded by a lot of whitespace in the following block

Results of inspect element/source

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: -8px;">
"Header Extension Record - Type 3"
"


p
       "
"

p
       "
</h1>
```

Relevant block in my code

```
</div>         
<h1 style ="text-align:center; margin-bottom: -8px;">Header Extension Record - Type 3</h1>
<table id="table3" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
```

Tablesorter code for problematic table heading:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // define pager options
                var pagerOptions = {
                    // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
                    container: $(".pager3"), size: 5,
                    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}'; possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
                    output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})',
                    // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter how many records are displayed. The space is made up by an empty
                    // table row set to a height to compensate; default is false
                    fixedHeight: true,
                    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
                    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
                    removeRows: false,
                    // go to page selector - select dropdown that sets the current page
                    cssGoto: '.gotoPage3'
                };

                $("#table3")
               .tablesorter({
                   theme: 'blue',
                   dateFormat: "mmddyy",
                   widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'pager', 'columns'],
                   widgetOptions: {
                       // output default: '{page}/{totalPages}'
                       // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
                       pager_output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})', // '{page}/{totalPages}'
                       pager_removeRows: false,

                       // include child row content while filtering, if true
                       filter_childRows: true,
                       // class name applied to filter row and each input
                       filter_cssFilter: 'tablesorter-filter',
                       // search from beginning
                       filter_startsWith: false,
                       // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive 
                       filter_ignoreCase: true
                   }
               })
               .tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
            });
</script>
```

**Update:** I've verified with complete certainty that the issue is not caused by the tablesorter script. I deleted all the tablesorter scripts, copied the scripts directly from a view that doesn't have this p character issue, and it still had the issue.

Comment: Is there any javascript that manipulates your html?

Comment: This looks like you have a markup error further up the page than the code you've posted. Nothing seems wrong with what you have in your question.

Comment: If you disable javascript in your browser, do the ghost p's still appear?

Comment: I'm using tablesorter, and have compared the scripts for each table, and they're all identical (except for variable names). But the issue is only on/ above one of the tables.

Comment: @frankhaverford does this happen in all browsers? What encoding is this page using?

Comment: Could you post the complete page source file? Might be useful

Comment: Just tested and it happens in internet explorer as well. Posting a 1500 line view is a solid way to get mass downvoted on this site lol.

Comment: True, but you can upload the file somewhere on the internet and post a link to it... I'm afraid we can't debug this for you without it. Btw, I'm not sure if it's a good practice to have a view consisting of 1500 lines...

Comment: Since p is a classic HTML markup character, the printed p characters bring into mind the markup errors that Greg Burghardt mentioned. That is why the View code would be useful